# Plotly modebar runs over two rows instead of one

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

My Plotly modebar runs over two rows instead of one when I create a plot.  Any thoughts?

[Picture of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltjEi.png)

```
exports.createPlot = function(){

  var trace1 = {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
    type: 'scatter'
  };

  var trace2 = {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
    type: 'scatter'
  };

  var data = [trace1, trace2];
  var layout = {
    showlegend: false,
    updatemenus: updatemenus,
  };

  Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout, {displayModeBar: true});

  //display mode set to true for the purpose of taking the screenshot
}
```

Usually modebar runs over one line like all examples I've seen.

**Update:**

Here is the CSS for the parent div.main and plot div.plot-panel:

```
div.main-content
{
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #EBEDEB;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  left: 162px;
  height: 86.6%;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 114px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
}

div.plot-panel
{
 border: 1px solid #EFF2EF;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 1%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: none;
 height: 350px;
 left: 600px;
 right: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 390px;
 width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: I created a JSFiddle with your code to test this (excluding the exports function), and the modebar looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3m5ghvda/1/ Could you show us the html style and (if any) css of you plot div?

Comment: Maybe you could edit the above fiddle to reproduce the issue? You generate your plotly chart in 'plot' div, but the css you added seems to be a parent of this div. I am sure the underlying problem for your modebar not showing in a single line has something to do with the 'plot' div container or the parent div.

Comment: Yeah, good suggestion.  I've been trying to remove CSS elements to see where the issue is.  But working to reproduce the problem is a good approach.  Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out.  The following CSS element was causing problems:

`.active {display: inherit; }`

Removed it and no more issues.  Thanks for the help.